# read a specific line from a txt file in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, parsing

In VB.net I'm trying to read in a specific line from a file.  An example of the line in the txt file is:

```
[PATH] = "/this/directory/run.exe"
```

Now I understand how to open the file for reading and writing in VB, but I need to parse out the path in the "" (quotation marks).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

--Adam

Comment: Can the path contain quotes?  If not, are you sure?  If so, how are they escaped?

Comment: Are you asking about how to locate this line in the file, or have you already read in and recognised this line and just need to parse out the path?

Comment: I need to find this line then parse out that section.  sorry for the nuisance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the line depends on what its distinguishing features are, but basically the idea would be to use LINQ.  For example:

```
Dim line As String = File.ReadAllLines(path).FirstOrDefault(Function (s As String) s.StartsWith("[PATH]")
```

This gets you the first line that begins with "[PATH]".  If you need better discrimination you could use a more sophisticated match such as a regex.

You can then extract the path from the line as per Rubens' or SLaks' answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim path As String = thatLine.Split("""")(1)
```

Comment: what do you mean for thatLine?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the path will never contain quotes, you can use a regular expression:

```
Dim regex As New Regex(".+=\s*""(.+)""")
Dim path As String = regex.Match(line).Groups(1).Value
```

Alternatively, you can search for the quotes and extract the part between them using string functions, like this: (This assumes that there will always be exactly two quotes)

```
Dim pathStart As String = line.IndexOf(""""c) + 1
Dim path As String = line.Substring(pathStart, line.LastIndexOf(""""c) - pathStart)
```