# How to read a specific line from a text file in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program that is supposed to write text into a text file, and should be able to read specific lines from a text file in VB (so if i needed to read a specific name I could select line 5 and it would display in the textbox). I am able to read the text from the text file but I do not know how to control a specific line.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
         Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("/text.txt", True)
         writer.WriteLine(txtFirstName.Text)
         writer.WriteLine(txtLastName.Text)
         writer.WriteLine("-------------------------------------")
         writer.Close()
    End Sub

     Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("/text.txt")
        Dim FirstName, LastName As String
        FirstName = reader.ReadLine()
        LastName = reader.ReadLine()
        reader.Close()
        txtFirstName.Text = FirstName
        txtLastName.Text = LastName
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtFirstName.Clear()
        txtLastName.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [read a specific line from a txt file in VB .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045705/read-a-specific-line-from-a-txt-file-in-vb-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read a specific line from a txt file in VB .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045705/read-a-specific-line-from-a-txt-file-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to read all lines up to the one you're interested in. For example:

```
Function ReadLineWithNumberFrom(filePath As String, ByVal lineNumber As Integer) As String
    Using file As New StreamReader(filePath)
        ' Skip all preceding lines: '
        For i As Integer = 1 To lineNumber - 1
            If file.ReadLine() Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber")
            End If
        Next
        ' Attempt to read the line you're interested in: '
        Dim line As String = file.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber")
        End If
        ' Succeded!
        Return line 
    End Using
End Function
```

This is because lines of text are variable-length records, and there is no way to guess the exact file offset where a specific line begins — not without an index.

If you frequently need to load a specific line, you have some more options:

- Load the complete text file into memory, e.g. by using `File.ReadAllLines("Foobar.txt")`. This returns a `String()` array which you can access by line number directly.
- Create a line number index manually. That is, process a text file line by line, and fill a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)` as you go. The keys are line numbers, and the values are file offsets. This allows you to `.Seek` right to the beginning of a specific line without having to keep the whole file in memory.

Comment: I did something very similar to this, but this would also work too. I ended up reading the amount of lines in the file and the used an algorithm that would jump to the specific line needed. Then read what was needed after that specific line. Sorry that it took so long to get back to you, I ended up fixing it before anyone got back to this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great solution, came across this today, worked a treat and have ensure I credited you in the code :-)

Comment: Got a question, I know this is old but still. Can you give a example of how to use this? I have around 5 lines of text in a file and for example I need to text of line 2. How do I do that? thanks!

Comment: @Rootel: If your text files are small in size, I would suggest that you keep it simple: `Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName) : Dim secondLine As String = lines(1)`. If you want the method from my answer: `Dim secondLine As String = ….ReadLineWithNumberFrom(fileName, 2)`. (I think. I haven't thought about the code shown above in a long while.) You would obviously need to define the shown function inside a `Class` or `Module`.In the former case, you'd then have to `New` up an object instance on which you can invoke the method.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\text.txt")
    Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
        allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    Loop
    reader.Close()
    txtFirstName.Text = ReadLine(5, allLines)
    txtLastName.Text = ReadLine(6, allLines)

End Sub

Public Function ReadLine(lineNumber As Integer, lines As List(Of String)) As String
    Return lines(lineNumber - 1)
End Function
```

If you had a file with this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
My Name
My LastName
```

your name textbox will have 'My Name' and your LastName textbox will have 'My LastName'.

Comment: I found this very helpful for a project I was working on, where I needed the values on a specific line in my input file. A very clear explanation, and perfect example. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple, try this:

```
Dim strLineText As String
Dim intLineNumber As Integer
LineNumber=3

myLine = File.ReadAllLines("D:\text.txt").ElementAt(LineNumber).ToString
```

Comment: Works very nicely but is very slow, do you know any way of speeding it up?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option

```
    Private Function readNthLine(fileAndPath As String, lineNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim nthLine As String = Nothing
    Dim n As Integer
    Try
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileAndPath)
            n = 0
            Do While (sr.Peek() >= 0) And (n < lineNumber)
                sr.ReadLine()
                n += 1
            Loop
            If sr.Peek() >= 0 Then
                nthLine = sr.ReadLine()
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
    Return nthLine
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it works fine. using VB Express
content inside test.txt:

```py
line1
line2
1
John
```

then in the form i add

```
textbox1
textbox2
label1
label2
```

and a `button`.

code inside the button:

```
     Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myLine As String
        Dim lineNumber0 As Integer
        lineNumber0 = 0
        Dim lineNumber1 As Integer
        lineNumber1 = 1
        Dim lineNumber2 As Integer
        lineNumber2 = 2
        Dim lineNumber3 As Integer
        lineNumber3 = 3

        TextBox1.Text=File.ReadAllLines("D:\test.txt").ElementAt(lineNumber0).ToString
        TextBox2.Text=File.ReadAllLines("D:\test.txt").ElementAt(lineNumber1).ToString
        Label1.Text = File.ReadAllLines("D:\test.txt").ElementAt(lineNumber2).ToString
        Label2.Text = File.ReadAllLines("D:\test.txt").ElementAt(lineNumber3).ToString

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple but effective solution:

```
Dim Reader As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\File.txt")(1)
MsgBox("Line 1: " + Reader)
```

The `MsgBox` should show the first line of `C:\File.txt`.

Comment: When select 5 it reads line 6

Comment: I know, sorry for the mistake