# Patching System in VB

Tags: vb.net, patch

I am trying to make a patching system or an updater if you will for my program. What I want it to do is download the patch list which is in a specific form in the text file.

Like this:

```
1   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patches/test1.rar
2   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patches/test2.rar
3   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patches/test3.rar
```

It's a tab in between 1 and the link.

And then I want it to check if the version number of the launcher or program at the moment matches the LAST patch in the PatchList.txt file. The last patch is version 3 and the launcher version at the moment is 0.

So if it doesn't match then it should start downloading one by one the patches. From patch 1 to patch 3.

I thought a loop statement would be best for it so I came up with this idea:

Make it download the PatchList.txt and then read each line individually. After it reads a line it will split where tab is so there will be two variables Version and PatchURL.

It will then check Version to see if it matches the launcher version and if it doesn't then it will download files from the PatchURL and apply it and then set the launcher version to the version of the current patch and then check again, if the version number and if it does match then there will be no updates so it will finish.

I don't know exactly how to put it into code. I have been trying for ages to be able to Download the txt file and read it line by line but I haven't been able to. I have tried many different things from StreamReader to StringReader and a bunch of other stuff.

I'd appreciate any help. This is very frustrating for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to download the file and read it in again, it's as easy as

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://your_url.txt", "local_tmp_path")
```

If you don't want to save the file on disk but read it in memory, you could use something like this:

```
Dim httpRequest  = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://your_url.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim httpResponse = DirectCast(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Dim line As String
Using responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), sr = New StreamReader(responseStream)
    Do
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim s = line.Split(new String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim version = s(0)
            Dim path = s(1)
            'Do something'
        End If
    Loop Until line Is Nothing
End Using
```

If you try to implement an update system for your software, better have a look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) first.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by download?

I would try the solution mentioned here.
[How to read a specific line from a text file in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708368/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vb)

Otherwise, I would reccommend using XML for the version file and just deserializing it.

Comment: Download it as in download the strings.