# Read all line from text file and then chose one

Tags: vb.net

I Have this CODE.

```
Public Function ReadCS1() As String
Dim st As String
  Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings.dat")
        st = sr.ReadLine()
    End Using
    Return st
 End Function
```

But what i want to do is if mytextbox1.text have value 1 then read and use Line 1, if mytextbox2.text have value two then read and use Line two, etc.

I'm new to VB.net and I do not understand how to fix this.

Comment: `Dim lineNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(mytextbox1.Text) : Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines() : Dim myLine As String = lines(lineNumber - 1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a specific line from a text file in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708368/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vb)

Comment: @41686d6564, you should absolutely not call `File.ReadAllLines`. It won't be a big deal for smaller files but imagine that you want the first line from a file with 1 million lines. `ReadAllLines` would read the entire file into an array, then you'd get the first element from that array. `File.ReadLines`, on the other hand, would only read the first line and then close the file.

Comment: @jmcilhinney In other situations, I would definitely not suggest calling `ReadAllLines()`. However, in this case, the OP said _"**Read all line** from text file and then chose one"_. Of course, there's the possibility that that's not actually what they _intended_ and that's why I referred them to the duplicate to see different options.

Comment: @41686d6564, fair point, although the title says "Read all line..." but the question itself seems to indicate otherwise. You generally wouldn't want to read the file multiple times so, if multiple lines will be required at different times, it may be best to call `ReadAllLines` once and then just get lines by index from that array as required.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Dim lineNumber As Integer ' zero-based line number here.

Dim line = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(lineNumber).First()
```

Note that the method is `ReadLines` and not `ReadAllLines`. The latter will read the entire file into an array first, then you would be taking an element from that array. The former reads lines and makes them available for processing as they are read, which means that you will only read as many lines as are required. If you want the first line then it will only read the first line. `Skip` will cause the specified number of lines to be read and discarded and then `First` will get the first line from the remainder.